# How to zoom out in DOTA2, spectator and SFX animator tool

Tags: dota-2

I was working on a new short film project, and I was wondering if there is any way of capturing video of the whole DOTA map, then slowly zooming in to a lane?

This would be in spectator/replay mode. I want to be able to zoom out completely for a bird's eye view of the whole playing arena.

I tried using `dota_camera_distance 5000` but that "wraps the map in clouds" and I can't see any aspect of the map.

Additionally, is there a way of hiding the top bar with hero icons, and the HUD?

Answer (score 0):

For hiding the bars I remember that I could use the following commands:

```
dota_hud_hide_topbar
dota_hud_hide_mainhud
dota_hud_hide_minimap
```

For removing any unnecessary graphic, you can override `vpk` and create the files you want to override. More info on how you can do that can be found [here](https://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=98241).

I have tried this a while back when trying to optimize the fps and it worked. I'm not sure now.

Good luck with your movie!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's possible to do that within DOTA

but if `dota_camera_distance 5000` does

> wraps the map in clouds

which is the fog of war, then you can try disabling it. Try these commands

```
 allvision
 normalvision -allvision
 normalvision dota_allvision_enable
 dota_allvision_disable Gives vision for both teams. Use -normalvision to undo this change.
```

On the other side, the approach I have seen done to achieve this effect is with SFM (Source film maker)

which I recommend you use to make your movie

Yes, you kinda have to learn something new, but you get more artistic control and better graphic results